# Batch Delete Folders That start a specific way

Tags: batch-file, cmd, lync

I'm using a batch file to delete files in AppData, essentially I want to clear the cache in skype/Lync. I'm adapting stuff from old code from about a decade ago, so maybe what I'm doing is dumb for today.

what I have so far

```
@echo off
echo Clearing Lync cache...
If %errorlevel%==1 goto Error
if "%LOCALAPPDATA%"=="" Set LOCALAPPDATA=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data
dir "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\sip_*" /b > list.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i in (list.txt) do del
```

So this get's the sip_ info and populates it into a text file named list. I want to then delete all of the folders matching those names. rmdir doesn't seem to work, but i could be wrong

Comment: That doesn't look like Bash.

Comment: That looks like batch syntax (i.e. DOS/Windows .BAT script)  -- which is spelled similarly to bash (a unix shell), but otherwise very different.

Comment: whoops yeah as everyone's pointing out I was silly and was saying bash when i meant batch

Comment: Try this: `for /F "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do rmdir "%%i"`. The `if %ErrorLevel%==1` at the beginning is completely useless...

Comment: Try This For Delete All Text File : Del "*.txt"

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, simple fix

```
cd %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Lync\
for /d /r %%i in (sip_*) do @rmdir /s "%%i"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to recurse sub-directories (`/R`)?

Comment: @aschipfl in this case would it be bad? These shouldn't be folders but shouldn't effect anything else. I want this to be as robust as possible since it will be deployed on many machines

Comment: Well, it's your decision if you want sub-directories or not, I just wanted to point it out; anyway, use `cd /D` rather than `cd`...